# Expanding on the jQuery post function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function in my code:

```
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray())
            .done(function (json) {
            }
```

From what I understand from the jQuery docs this is a shortcut. What I would like to do is to change so that it allows me to have some function that executes on success and some function that executes on error. Is this possible to do? All I see is a .done?

```
$.ajax({
   url: target,
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,
   success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
```

Comment: Why can't you then just use `$.ajax()`?

Comment: That would be okay but I don't really understand where to put the $form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray() in the ajax call. Also the jQuery way does look a bit cleaner if only it was possible.

Comment: @MarieJ `$.ajax()` is still the jQuery way :).

Comment: @MarieJ `$.ajax()` **is** jQuery. In fact, it's the function that gets called in the code when you use `$.post()`.

Answer (score 5):

Since [all the jQuery ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), including `$.post()`, return a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, you can use the [Deferred object API](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) if you don't want to use a full-out `$.ajax()` call.

```
$.post(/* snip */).fail(function () {/* snip */});
```

Comment: I read about this but cannot understand what they mean by deferred object API.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use .success() .error() and .complete() as chained methods to .post() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." [source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: Okay well that's a good thing for me to note. thanks. But how do I actually code these? It seems like callbacks are a bit different. I guess am I correct in saying all I would need to do is add a .fail and put in that function the error code? Does .done always mean success ?